# Android Fullscreen Theme is not working

Tags: android, themes, fullscreen

I just started "real" android programming (programmed with Unity3D before) today. I made a very simple app design and now I want it to be fullscreen. I searched for it and found this code:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But this is not working for my app. When I try to start my app I recieve the error: "My Application wurde beendet". That should be something like "My Application was quit" in english.
When I change just only this one single line into the following, my app works fine:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I don't change anything else except this single line so the problem should be caused by this line. What am I doing wrong? Thats what my manifest-file looks like in complete, maybe it can be of help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the logcat:

```js
05-13 12:44:42.395  12101-12101/com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-13 12:44:42.511  12101-12101/com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-13 12:44:42.512  12101-12101/com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication, PID: 12101
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication/com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.dunkel.jonas.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5938)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Could you please post the logcat..

Comment: Sorry wasn't at home the last week so just added the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

With the activity you are using it is requesting a theme from the support Library.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

You can try this.

```
<application
...
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
</application>
```

Comment: Now the logcat has changed:

Comment: Ok sorry, seems like I can't post the logcat here. It's too long

Comment: I've never seen that logcat error before.  I would suggest trying "Build->Clean Project" and testing again.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android_manifest.xml, at application level put,

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</application>
```

and in the activity that you want to make full screen put,

```
<activity

     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
     ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but thats not working for me. My app still crashes with the same error when I try to launch it.